December 2024 Photo Competition: Movement
The topic is "movement", so photos containing some type of movement (e.g., through the air, something running, etc.). Long exposures are fine too.
The contest will end at the end of December (UTC time). The following rules apply:

Up to three photos per answer. Photos in the same answer should be related.
You can make up to three posts (attempts).
Do not delete posts if you don't get votes: you posted it, stand by it. (You have two more attempts if your first one doesn't work out.)
All submissions should have a line with when and where the photo(s) was/were taken, along with a description of the subject.
The photo has to be taken by the person who posted it, or by a travel partner (needs to be named).
Keep it nice, CoC-compliant, non-offensive, and suitable for work.
If you have people recognizable in the photo, you must either (a) have their permission to post the photo or (b) make them unrecognizable.
If you disagree with a photo, please consider leaving a comment on it or bringing it up in chat. For the purposes of judging, only upvotes will be considered; downvotes will not affect the score of the photo.
The photo may have been taken any time.
If there is no tie for the highest number of upvotes at the end of the month, the winner will be announced then; if there is, the voting period may extend beyond the month.
If you'd like to suggest a theme for a future photo competition, please add it to the list of possible photo competition topics. Also, you can join us in chat to help us make the decision on which topic to choose.


wave after wave after wave hitting the coast, movement since the beginning of time

I took this picture on the 31st of January, 2015, in Ericeira - Portugal, just before a storm came in from the South...

Canon EOS400, f/7.1, 1/1000sec., ISO400, 100mm focal length


Humming bird feeding frenzy in Virginia USA during the summer of 2019.

I took these two photos at Seafair 2024 from Seattle, WA. I think this is an F35-B.



While not moving yet, The Different (yes that is its name) gave the impression of speed already while not finished yet.

This photo was taken 24 June 2023, in Hoorn, the Netherlands.
After they finished the work it got a flashy paint job in white and red with black details, but I think the naked carbon was beautiful already.

I took this picture on Aug 5th, 2022, while our powerboat was cruising at 62 mph (this is over 114 km per hour) on Benin River, in Delta State (Nigeria). The craft was equipped with 3x250 hp Yamaha engines and was hosting 7 people plus the staff.
I like how the wind at some speed distorts the horizon and the contours of the subjects in the photos.

